# tabularx vs ltablex

Tags: tabularx, ltablex

I have been working with tables spanned over multiple pages as well as I want "x" functionality as well. I have been successfully working with tabularx (along with threeparttable) for now. It seems to me that there isn't any table type which one can do using one package can't be done using another package. So, can we just assume that tabularx and ltablex can replace each other and there is no advantages one offer over another? I am inquisitive what are the pros and cons of one package over another. Any insightful comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Your write-up is, I'm afraid, a bit confusing. In particular, the `tabularx` environment cannot (at least by itself) span multiple pages. Please clarify your objective.

Comment: @Mico I meant tabularx + threeparttable can span pages. No any specific advantages of ltablex + threeparttable over ltablex and vice versa?

Comment: More precisely, it is `threepartablex` that allows for splitting across pages.

Answer (score 6):

The `X` functionality in `ltablex` is implemented by `tabularx` and the multipage functionality in `ltablex` is implemented by `longtable`. `ltablex` just includes both packages and supplies a bit of glue so they work better together.